# Bash sorting fails sometimes

Tags: bash, sorting, double

Here is the problem :

```
echo -e " 1.0101010101010102 Ok \n 
     1.00 Ok \n 
     1.010204081632653 Ok \n 
     1.010752688172043 Ok \n 
     1.0 FAIL \n 
     1.010989010989011 Ok" 
| sort -n
```

returns

```
 1.00 Ok 
 1.0101010101010102 Ok 
 1.010204081632653 Ok 
 1.010752688172043 Ok 
 1.010989010989011 Ok
 1.0 FAIL
```

Apparently the bug occurs only with the "i.0"-form values. It also has the same weird result with sorting option "-g".

Does anyone has any clue about why it does that, and how to correct the sorting... ?

Comment: works for me.  `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.13`

Comment: works for me. `sort (GNU coreutils) 5.93`

Comment: @ChristianG. Can you try `sort -sn`?

Comment: @ChristianG What version of `sort` do you have? Check with `sort --version`.

Comment: Btw i have this version "(GNU coreutils) 8.20".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using GNU sort, you need to use `-g` rather than `-n` to sort floating point values. `-n` is only for integers.

Most probably, your problem is that your locale is not set to the `C` locale. Many locale settings interfere with numeric sort, particularly of floating point numbers (where some locales expect to see comma as a decimal separator). Try this:

```
LC_COLLATE= sort -g
```

If you're using a different sort, you'll need to read its documentation.

Comment: Thanks, it finally worked with "LC_COLLATE=C", even with option -n.